# How to start a local substrate node using python substrate interface

Tags: substrateinterface, python, polkascan

I am using python substrate Interface (https://github.com/polkascan/py-substrate-interface) to interact with the substrate node.

How to start my local substrate-node-template using python for substrate interface?

Answer (score 2):

As you note in your question py-substrate-interface is just used to interface with a node, a node that is already running. If you are interested in discovering more about how to set up and run your own nodes I would recommend visiting https://docs.substrate.io/

And a maybe more direct hands on entry point to launch your node: https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/get-started/build-local-blockchain/